# Can I migrate an existing openSUSE system to use disk encryption?

Tags: opensuse, disk-encryption

Currently, my laptop is running openSUSE Tumbleweed, but it doesn't have any disk encryption configured.

Is it possible to switch to full disk encryption or at least home directory encryption after the fact?

I'm able to boot from a different volume and/or use external storage as a staging area to make the migration. I just don't want to reconfigure my whole system again.

Comment: Moving home should be easy if you can provide a new (encrypted) partition for it to live on – `/home/(username)` is just a convention, `/etc/passwd` entries are what really stores the location of your home dir.

Comment: Have you tried using YaST? I believe you can choose "Encrypt Device" for an existing partition, but I'm not sure how it's implemented, since I didn't want to encrypt my own partition. At the very least it seems like you could (1) save a copy of your current /home partition, (2) use YaST to convert the /home to encrypted, and (3) restore the files from wherever you saved them at.

Comment: @Lee-Man I believe this would wipe the partition, but I haven't tried yet. I'll see what it does.